# AWS - Error 502 between CloudFront and EC2 SSL certificate - Mobile App

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, lets-encrypt

- I have a EC2 Instance in which I've installed an SSL certificate via LetsEncrypt
- The Instance hosts a FastApi and Gunicorn which serves as server for a mobile app
- There's an elastic IP attached to the EC2 instance
- All inbounds and outbounds EC2 ports are opened
- I have imported in the Certificate Manager (east-2 Virginia) the SSL certificate generated by LetsEncrypt
- I have created an hosted zone in Route53 adding a domain ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) and creating the CAA (0 issue "letsencrypt.org") + changed the nameservers in godaddy as per the ones in the Route53 NS
- I have created a CloudFront distribution having as origin the Public IPv4 DNS of the EC2 instance, redirecting HTTP to HTTPS, setting the Custom SSL certificate equal to the one uploaded in the Certificate Manager (LetsEncrypt) and in the Alternate domain name (CNAME) added the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
- I have added in Route53, in the A record, the CloudFront Distribution domain name

Given these premises, in the EC2 instance there is not a landing html page (like hello world!) to be reached if the CloudFront Distribution domain name or the domain name is pinged.

However, If I ping it, I get the 502 error (502 ERROR The request could not be satisfied.
CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time).

The domain was validated in the SSLlab without throwing errors except a "Chain issues Incorrect order, Extra certs" in the "Additional Certificates section" (not in the "Server Key and Certificate #1") and the X-Cache says: Error from CloudFront.

How can I fix the 502 error?

EDIT

I've posted the solution in the comment

Comment: It's probably either 1 connectivity (local firewall, security groups or NACL), 2 the server isnt responding to the hostname you expect (instance or DNS problem), or 3 the app is setup properly but returning an error (maybe CloudFront is not passing a required header or something app specific). Check the logs on your instance for connections from CloudFront and any application specific error logs. Edit your question to add your findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to keep everything as above stated *but*:

- remove the ssl certificate from the instance
- generate a new ssl certificate in Certificate Manager from Amazon (this also implies creating records in Route 53 of the CNAME of the new certificate and selecting the new certificate in the Cloudfront distribution).

At the end the issue was a conflict between the two ssl certificates. Only one had to be kept.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, you MUST use fullchain.pem certificate instead of the shorter cert.pem one. Otherwise cloudfront will fail to load non `/` url if it is a single page app.